# TFS multiple users using a single workspace

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I am using TFS 2012. Right now if a user creates a workspace then it will be only accessed by the user who created it. Is there any option where the a workspace can be accessed by more than one user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can make your workspace a "public workspace" which means that other users on the computer can check-out files and check-in from that workspace.  This is available in the Add and Edit Workspace dialogs, in the Advanced settings:

[image]

Comment: Does public workspace can be accessed by a user from another machine? I want to access it from other PC also.